# how do I use groups to provide access to oracle apex apps

Tags: oracle, authorization, oracle-apex

I'm trying to use the built in groups functionality to control access to my applications in Oracle APEX.  I have the following code in Expression 1 of the Authorization Scheme that I'm trying to use:

```
DECLARE
    VAL BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    IF (
        APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP(p_group_name=>'Problem Solvers')  OR
        APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP(p_group_name=>'OPS') OR
        APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP(p_group_name=>'SUPERUSER') )then
    VAL := TRUE;
    else VAL := FALSE;
    end if;
    RETURN VAL;
END;
```

This code will prevent access to all pages in my app, but I can no longer access the login page (unless I'm already logged in from the development interface).  I tried including an additonal "OR :APP_PAGE_ID = 101" in the conditions, but that results in unexpected behavior. In particular, when an authorized user logs out, and an unauthorized user subsequently logs in, they can still get access to the whole app.  I tried setting up clear session cache, and clear application cache processes on the login page, but to no avail.  Any ideas on what the right way to do this is?

Comment: I used this code for authorization at the app level.  I can use this at the page level and it works just fine, but I really don't like having to go to each page individually  to set up authorization.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running Apex 4.2: You should set "Run on Public Pages" to No. Your login page should be public with no security checks.